# Kml placemarks do not show anymore with last version of google-earth plugin

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

Since i have upgraded to last version of the google-earth plugin (april 23 2013) the placemarks of my usual KML files do not show anymore! - in fact i can't see any placemarks from any KML files, even from google-earth exemples/code - either for Firefox or iExplorer. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Ex: i can't seee no more the placemarks in here: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/dom-tree/index.html

Comment: Here my project: http://genepoulin.net/places/   .... and the kml file with the placemarks: http://genepoulin.net/places/corinne.kml

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I found a solution in an earlier thread!

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-earth-browser-plugin/XVx7fJBFDeI

Comment: External links might not always be valid. Instead of posting a link-only answer, might you be able to summarize the key parts?